# Is there a unicode range that is a copy of the first 128 characters?

Tags: text, unicode

I would like to be able to put  and other characters into a text without it being interpreted by the computer. So was wondering is there a range that is defined as mapping to the same glyphs etc as the range 0-0x7f (the ascii range).

Please note I state that the range 0-0x7f is the same as ascii, so the question is not what range maps to ascii.

I am asking is there another range that also maps to the same glyphs. I.E when rendered will look the same. But when interpreted may be can be seen as a different code.

so I can write

print "**hello "world"**"

characters in bold avoid the 0-0x7f (ascii range)

Additional:
I was meaning homographic and behaviourally, well everything the same except a different code point. I was hopping for the whole ascii/128bit set, directly mapped (an offset added to them all).

The reason: to avoid interpretation by any language that uses some of the ascii characters as part of its language but allows any unicode character in literal strings e.g. (when uft-8 encoded) C, html, css, …

I was trying to retro-fix the idea of “no reserved words” / “word colours” (string literals one colour, keywords another, variables another, numbers another, etc) so that a string literal or variable-name(though not in this case) can contain any character.

Comment: What do you mean by "interpreted by the computer"? Either you're dealing with text or you're dealing with other data. Mixing those in things that are intended for text (e.g. strings) is a bad idea.

Comment: Some text is rendered using the glyphs. Some text is interpreted. e.g. print "hello world"; here at some point the text hello world will be rendered it to glyphs but the rest is just interpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question asked is “No”, as @tripleee described, but the following note might be relevant if the purpose is trickery or fun of some kind:

The printable ASCII characters excluding the space have been duplicated at U+FF01 to U+FF5E, but these are fullwidth characters intended for use in CJK texts. Their shape is (and is meant to be) different: ｈｅｌｌｏ　　ｗｏｒｌｄ. (Your browser may be unable to render them.) So they are not really homographic with ASCII characters but could be used for some special purposes. (I have no idea of what the purpose might be here.)

Comment: I was reading the samba docs, and it mentioned remapping some dos/ms-windows reserver characters (such as \) to the 0xf000 range. I think this answer explains it.

Comment: @richard, I think such mapping is something different. U+F000 is in a Private Use Area (PUA), U+E000 to U+F8FF, which means that they are locations that can be used for anything you like, by special agreement between interested parties. They could even be used for copies of normal characters, or for their variants that do not exist as separately coded standard characters. The U+FF01 to U+FF5E range is different (standard characters, not PUA).

Answer (score 3):

I interpret the question to mean "is there a set of code points which are homographic with the low 7-bit ASCII set".  The answer is no.

There are some code points which are conventionally rendered homographically (e.g. Cyrillic upparcase А U+0410 looks identical to ASCII 65 in many fonts, and quite similar in most fonts which support this code point) but they are different code points with different semantics.  Similarly, there are some code points which basically render identically, but have a specific set of semantics, like the non-breaking space U+00A0 which renders identically to ASCII 32 but is specified as having a particular line-breaking property; or the RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK U+2019 which is an unambiguous quotation mark, as opposed to its twin ASCII 39, the "apostrophe".

But in summary, there are many symbols in the basic ASCII block which do not coincide with a homograph in another code block.  You might be able to find homographs or near-homographs for your sample sentence, though; I would investigate the IPA phonetic symbols and the Greek and Cyrillic blocks.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the Unicode standard you use.

In UTF-8, the first 128 characters have the exact ASCII counterparts as code numbers. In UTF-16, the first 128 ASCII characters are between 0x0000 and 0x007F (2 bytes).

Comment: Erm, there is only *one* Unicode standard and it is defined in a way that the first 256 characters are identical to Latin 1, which also maens that the first 128 characters are identical to ASCII. Unicode code points themselves are always 21 bits, regardless of the transformation format you're using. Of course the latter controls how they map to bytes.